# Need pandas optimized code with 1 million stock data

Tags: pandas, vectorization, apply

Currently my code is

```
self.df['sma'] = self.df['Close'].rolling(window=30).mean()

self.df['cma'] = self.df.apply(lambda x: self.get_cma(x), axis=1)

def get_cma(self, candle):
    if np.isnan(candle['sma']):
        return np.nan
    secma = (candle['sma'] - self.previous_cma if self.previous_cma is not None else 0) ** 2 
    ka = 1 - (candle['var']/secma) if candle['var'] < secma else 0
    cma = ((ka * candle['sma']) + ((1 - ka) * self.previous_cma)) if self.previous_cma is not None else candle[self.src]
    self.previous_cma = cma
    return cma
```

Can the above optimized to make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may already know, the secret to performance with Pandas is to do this in vectorized form.  This means no `apply`.  Here are the first few steps you need to take to speed up your code, by extracting parts of your `get_cma()` function to their vectorized equivalents.

```
if np.isnan(candle['sma']):
    return np.nan
```

This early exit is not needed in `get_cma()`, we can do this instead:

```
self.df['cma'] = np.nan
valid = self.df['sma'].notnull()
# this comment is a placeholder for step 2
self.df.loc[valid, 'cma'] = self.df[valid].apply(self.get_cma, axis=1)
```

This not only vectorizes the first two lines of `get_cma()`, it means `get_cma()` is now only called on not-null rows, rather than every row.  Depending on your data that alone may provide a noticeable speedup.

If that's not enough, we need a bigger hammer.  The fundamental problem is that each iteration of `get_cma()` depends on the previous, so it is not easy to vectorize.  So let's use Numba to JIT compile the code.  First we need to get rid of `apply` by using a good old `for` loop over the individual columns, which is equivalent (and will still be slow).  Note this is a free (global) function, not a member function, and it takes NumPy arrays instead of Pandas types, because those are what Numba understands:

```
def get_cma(sma, var, src):
    cma = np.empty_like(sma)
    # take care of the initial value first, to avoid unnecessary branches later
    cma[0] = src[0]

    # now do all remaining rows, cma[ii-1] is previous_cma and is never None
    for ii in range(1, len(sma)):
        secma = (sma[ii] - cma[ii-1]) ** 2 
        ka = 1 - (var[ii] / secma) if var[ii] < secma else 0
        cma[ii] = (ka * sma[ii]]) + ((1 - ka) * cma[ii-1])

    return cma
```

Call it like this, passing the required columns as NumPy arrays:

```
valid_rows = self.df[valid]
self.df.loc[valid, 'cma'] = get_cma(
    valid_rows['sma'].to_numpy(),
    valid_rows['var'].to_numpy(),
    valid_rows[self.src].to_numpy())
```

Finally, after confirming the code works, decorate `get_cma()` to compile it with Numba automatically like this:

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def get_cma(sma, var, src):
    ...
```

That's it.  Please let us know how much faster this runs on your real data.  I expect it will be plenty fast enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. Yes I tried and its much faster (14 times). Its failing with @numba.njit File "chart.py", line 96:
        def calculator_cma(self,var,sma, src):
        res = np.zeros(src.shape)
        for i in range(0, res.shape[0]):
            if np.isnan(sma[i]):
                res[i] = src[i]
                continue
            secma = (sma[i] -res[i-1]) ** 2
            ka = 1 - (var[i]/secma) if var[i] < secma else 0
            res[i] = ((ka * sma[i]) + ((1 - ka) * res[i-1]))
        return res

Comment: You can't make the method be a member function of the class.  It cannot take `self`. 
 Numba doesn't let you decorate a single member function of a class.  You just need to move the function outside the class and remove the `self` parameter, as I showed in the answer.

Comment: from 1 min, now its takings 4 seconds. superb answer, Yes corrected and made the function out of class.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  You can "accept" this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left if your problem is resolved.